# How to create a global list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a class for the model of a credit card with parameters like cardHolderName, cardNumber, cVV and expiryDate. I want to create a list of credit cards that is accessible across all the pages in my application to which I can add cards, delete cards and edit cards. How do I create a global list in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with any of the available state management solutions. I think the easiest would be with [GetX State Management](https://pub.dev/packages/get) because you don't have to wrap your whole app in a `Provider` widget to have access to the list.

It would be as simple as this.

```
class CreditCardController extends GetxController {

// List below is accessible from anywhere by 
// Get.find<CreditCardController().creditCardList

  List<CreditCardModel> creditCardList = []; 

}
```

Initialize the Getx controller in your main like this

```
void main() {
  Get.put(CreditCardController());
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then from anywhere in the app you find that same list by finding that controller

```
final controller = Get.find<CreditCardController>();

// then treat it like any other list
controller.creditCardList.add(...);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do it with a service class instead.